# send a packet with probability p

Tags: probability

I have a computer network and I want to choose random connections between them. How can I randomly choose different connections between the nodes? For example, a node sends a packet and chooses the destination with probability $p$. (I mean, the node with probability $p$ makes a connection, otherwise it does not make a connection / does not send a packet).

Answer (score 2):

Find the stats package for your preferred programming language and use a random number generator. It's common to use a uniform(0,1) variable and check if it is less than p. E.g., in python you might do something like:

```
p = .4
if rand() < p: foo()
```